# Pass data between Backbone Views on different router states

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application

I have a router that on trigger of a new route, it calls a function to destroy the currently showing page view and instantiate the new one.

Since only one page view is alive at any given time, how do I get data from one page view to pass to another page view in the case that there is a dependency between the two views?

I could pass data on the url, but what happens if the data I need to pass is a collection as I believe there is a restriction to the length of the url in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good solution here that uses local storage https://stackoverflow.com/a/14802459/182890

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put an model into mediator-js and store there your sharing data?
When initializing a view fetch that model and use it, update it.

Mediator is like an singleton. I use it between different layouts/views in big SPA.